# distance of a line connecting $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, vector-analysis, problem-solving

I created this weird problem in my head which might be trivial or rather complicated but I somehow can't figure out how to solve it:

Imagine you have a bar/line connecting the graphs of $e^x$ and $ln(x)$ at $e^0$ and $\ln(1)$ (which has the distance of $\sqrt2$ ).

And now you move that bar along the x axes without changing its slope (which is $-\sqrt2$) where it intersects the $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$ values accordingly.

How could you describe the length of that bar with a function of $x$?

Here are 4 of those graph-connecting lines and what I'm looking for is the length of any line $d(x)$

[image: Here are 4 of those graph-connecting lines and what I'm looking for is the length of any line <span class=]$d(x)$" />

Comment: So far you have three different answers for your function of $x$.  This is because it it unclear from your questions whether your pairs of points are parametrised by $(e^x,x),(x,e^x)$ or $(x,\log_e(x)),(\log_e(x),x)$ or something else.  Your chart shows a particular $d(x)$ but not which $x$ this corresponds to (the left end, the right end or the mid point?)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the slope of the line is $-1$, not $-\sqrt{2}$. Let's take $x$ to be the location of the intersection with $e^x$.

The equation of a line with slope $-1$ that passes through $(x, e^x)$ is $y' - e^x = -(x' - x)$, or $y' = x + e^x - x'$. This will intersect $\ln(x)$ when $e^{y'} = x'$. Putting this into the equation for the line, we see that the intersection is at $(e^x, x)$. We could also come to this result using the fact that $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$ are reflections over $y = x$.

The distance between these points is $\sqrt{(e^x - x)^2 + (x - e^x)^2}$, so we have
$$
d(x) = \sqrt{2}(e^x - x)
$$

Comment: My bad, the slope is -1 of course; I confused it with the length. But now I have two different results which both seem to be plausible.

Comment: @juliangst tomi used the intersection with $\ln(x)$ as his x-coordinate instead, so the two answers are equivalent.

Comment: oh you're right. I came up with that problem under the shower and didn't spent much time thinking about it xD

Answer (score 2):

Point P is given by $(x,\ln x)$

Point Q is given by $(\ln x, x)$

So distance $d= \sqrt {(x-\ln x)^2+(\ln x-x)^2}$

$d= \sqrt {2(x-\ln x)^2}   $

$d= \sqrt 2 |x-\ln x|  $